# Shorten jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for asking, but i am really newbie in jquery.

```
$(".productTopMenu").click(function() {
        $("#breadcrumbs").html("Home / <strong>Product</strong>");
    });

$(".downloadTopMenu").click(function() {
        $("#breadcrumbs").html("Home / <strong>Download</strong>");
    });
```

this is a breadcrumbs. every .productTopMenu clicked, #breadcrumbs will call the text. 
if there is 15 pages, i must put 13 more copies of that script.
how to shorten that script like :

```
.productTopMenu = Home / <strong>Product</strong>
.downloadTopMenu = "Home / <strong>Download</strong>
```

the text always called inside #breadcrumbs.

is there a way to shorten this script ?
thanks in advance
any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Is there a div, span or any other element that contains the text for the clicked elements (Product, Downloads etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$('[class$="TopMenu"]').click(function() {
    $("#breadcrumbs").html("Home / <strong>" + getNameFromClass(this.className)
        + "</strong>");
});

function getNameFromClass(theClass) {
      // take substring and make title case here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Although your answer is going in the right direction it's not of much help to a jquery newbie. Try to be a bit more precise and maybe add an example.

Comment: @TJ There is some examples in the jquery's manual, so I tend not to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but this should work:

```
// your data as an array containing objects
var item = [
{
    "selector" : ".productTopMenu",
    "label" : "Product"
},
{
    "selector" : ".downloadTopMenu",
    "label" : "Download"
}
],

i = item.length - 1,
$breadcrumbs = $('#breadcrumbs');  // Dom Cache

while (i >= 0) {
    (function (i) {
        $(item[i].selector).click(function () {
        $breadcrumbs.html('Home / <strong>' + item[i].label + '</strong>');
         });
   }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each of this menu elements the same calls, a unique ID and have a mapping `id -> text`:

```
var paths = {
    'productTopMenu': "Home / <strong>Product</strong>",
    'downloadTopMenu': "Home / <strong>Download</strong>"
};

$('.menuItem').click(function() {
    if(paths[this.id]) {
        $("#breadcrumbs").html(paths[this.id])
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/qvFgW/)

You could also use a `data-` attribute to store some identifier, it does not have to be the `id` attribute.

Of course there are other ways. You have to decide how automatic or flexible you want the solution to be.

Comment: I am really interested with your script, i have try it but it does not work,. Could you show me just simple complete script, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has suggested, take the name from an existing element, and then use common class to hook up the click delegate.

If you haven't got the text as it should appear, you could try outputting it as a `data-*` attribute...

```
<a href="#" data-title="Downloads" />Go to Downloads</a>
```

That way you can control the name separately from everything else, at least.